# How do I define a structure with variable members based off another member in C?

Tags: c, object, structure, storage

I have a structure in C :

```
typedef struct storing_fields
{
  int x;
  int y;
  int z;
};
```

There are cases when, based on a certain value of `x`, I don't need `y` and `z`, but there are also cases when I need them all.

My question is:

- How do I define a structure with variable members based off another member in C?

Comment: What do you call "best" ? Maybe (probably) the best way is not to care.

Comment: Is memory space a concern? How many of those objects will you have in your code? Hundreds, thousands, millions?

Comment: I would try for example use a pointer maybe and allocate 1 or 3 int to it depending on if I need the y and z if space matter that much.
`typedef struct storing_fields{int* coords;}`

Comment: Are you cornered into using C, or is C++ an option?

Comment: Not enough information but for the above, rather than a structure, use an `int*` pointing to an array of 1, 2, 3, or however many `int`s you want.

Comment: @RobertS - Your edits (with the exception of _`x`, `y` and `z`_) are making too many assumptions, and potentially moved too far away from intent of OP's words.  Use caution not to _suggest solutions that impose your understanding of OP intent_.  I suggest a rollback with the exception of the three variables.

Comment: @ryyker We should let the OP decide whether my edits fit his thoughts or not. Else, yes a rollback is appreciated.

Comment: Probably overkill, but this question makes me think of OO-C. Objects are defined in C structs. The first field of the struct may be a class identifier, like Objective-C `isa` pointer.

Comment: @SamStewart Does the the question how it is now with my edits, fit to the issue you have asked for? I´d just want to make a few things clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Memory-wise the common practice is to keep a `size` parameter as the first member of the struct, this way you are quick to iterate the elements efficitently.

You can keep the members in the struct declaration but `malloc` however bytes you need. But you could also declare several types of your struct, but have an array of them declared as uniform type, like this:

```
typedef struct storing_fields_full
{
  size_t size;
  int x,y,z;
} storing_fields_full;

typedef struct storing_fields3
{
  size_t size;
  int x,y,z;
} storing_fields3;


typedef struct storing_fields2
{
  size_t size;
  int x,y;
} storing_fields2;


typedef struct storing_fields1
{
  size_t size;
  int x;
} storing_fields1;
```

Make sure that `size` member is always equal to `sizeof(storing_fieldsx)` and that your members are always in the same order. If you have the different types "mixed" in an array, you can iterate them efficiently like that:

```
int i;
storing_fields_full *data;
for (i=0, data=some_data; i<num_elements; i++, data+=data->size)
{
   // do stuff with your data here
}
```

Assuming that you are always aware what kind of data actually is or is not present in the struct, you should be good to go. Otherwise, you can always test it like this:

```
if (data->size > offsetof(storing_fields_full,z)) // data is present
```

Note that this does not save much memory in the exact example provided, as the overhead of the `size` argument might actually increase memory size, but if the structures you are planning to use are much larger, it might save a lot of memory. For smaller structures, like the ones in the example, just leaving unused members will probably increase the iteration speed and will be much easier to manage from code as well.

Comment: You are adding 1 int in each structure to potentially save 1 or 2. If the repartition is uniform, you will change 3 blocs of 3 ints (9 in total) for 1 bloc of 4 ints, 1 of 3 and one of 2. Which gives same total of 9.... Not downvoting because it is indeed the correct way to handle structures or varying lenght, but unsure that it is really appropriate here. IMHO you should add a remark to your post warning that the memory gain may not worth it **in that precise use case**.

Comment: You are correct. I assumed that the example data is not representative of the actual, much bigger structures. I'll amend my answer.

Comment: And I now can upvote a better answer :-)

Comment: One funny side note (considering only the simple example given in question): On typical modern hardware, `size_t` has the size of two `int`s, and to get the `size` member in `storing_fields1` properly aligned even in arrays, we'd most likely get additional padding bytes in the size of one `int`, so in total, the struct would even grow instead of shrink...

Comment: I wouldn't have created an own type for `storing_fields_full`, though, but, as identical, only have aliased it to `storing_fields3`.

Comment: That is true, but even if you shrink `size` parameter to `uint8_t`, the following members will most likely be padded to 4 or 8-byte alignment anyways, as this is the first element, so it doesn't really make much sense to use a smaller `size` type. And with `storing_fields_full` you are also correct, but I didn't want to overcomplicate the answer. (additionally you could use macros to define the smaller structs)

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to handle two types of structures, one with just `x`, one with `x, y, z`. How do you distinguish them? The logic to do so is costly in terms of runtime. You won't be able to have e.g. an array of those (unless you pad up to maximal size... and that is just keeping the three members anyway). If you handle the structures in the heap, the overhead your `malloc` introduces is quite possibly much larger than any savings. And the compiler might pad out to some round size, making the in-memory structures the same size.

If you can segregate them into one/three member structures, handling gets easier... but the other logic probably gets much messier.

Keep Jon Bentley's advice in his (sadly out of print) "Writing Efficient Programs": Look at the overall architecture, select data structures and programs carefully, then consider local tweaks. *Measure* the effect of any changes, people are notoriously bad at guessing at hot spots in code (time or space wise) and estimating effects of changes. In this case, check what your compiler does, often "careful hand optimizations" suggested in oldish texts nowadays are done as a matter of course by a modern optimizing compiler (you'd be surprised at the often wildly different code the compiler writes from your source), and your work is for naught (or confuses the compiler into generating worse code). Only for extremely heavily used code does your time squeezing out the last percent of performance pay off.

Answer (score 0):

Well have to make some assumptions. Let say you want to save space and also that you dont need `y` and `z` when `x` is less than `10`. Also assuming that on your machine `sizeof(int*) == 4` and also `sizeof(int) == 4`. Then I would might do this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct storing_fields
{
    int* coords;
} storing_fields;

int main(void)
{
    int x, y, z;
    storing_fields coordinates;

    printf("Enter x, y and z\n");
    scanf("%d\n%d\n%d", &x, &y, &z);
    printf("x=%d, y=%d, z=%d\n", x, y, z);   

    if (x < 10) {
        coordinates.coords = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
        coordinates.coords[0] = x;
    } else {
        coordinates.coords = (int*) malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
        coordinates.coords[0] = x;        
        coordinates.coords[1] = y;        
        coordinates.coords[2] = z;        
    }

    if (sizeof(coordinates.coords)/sizeof(int) == 1)
        printf("x=%d\n", coordinates.coords[0]);
    else if (sizeof(coordinates.coords)/sizeof(int) == 3)
        printf("x=%d, y=%d, z=%d\n", coordinates.coords[0],
                                     coordinates.coords[1],
                                     coordinates.coords[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

So conditinally allocating memory and when accesing field also use conditon to decide whether or not there is actually an y and z. (2nd and 3rd coordinate)